# Manually creating target variable, getting f1 score 1

Tags: classification, predictive-models, feature-selection, model-evaluation, feature-engineering

I am building a classifier for user engagement in my website. Basically, since there are no "proxy" for engagement, i.e. there is no pre-defined target variable, I came up with minimum thresholds above which, a user is considered **"engaged"** else **"not_engaged"**.

The two variables are: `total read articles` and `total reading time`; I have set a minimum to either of them for a user to take value 1 or 0 (engaged or not_engaged) the problem is that I am getting the f1-score=1 for both "0" and "1", using ensemble models (RF, Gradient Boosting, etc) as seen below:

[image]

I also noticed that the predict_proba method in sklearn returns only 0s and 1s under this f1score=1 case, which is not what I want. I want some randomness in the predictions. I don't want to say, user X is 0% engaged, user Y is 100% engaged, rather, X is 14% engaged, Y is 85% engaged.

Does this happen because I have set the minimum thresholds for "engaged" user? How would you solve it in this case in order not to have a "perfect" model?

Thanks.

Comment: Are "total read articles" and "total reading time" also predictors? If they are, then your model will predict perfectly since your variable to be predicted is a direct combination of the predictors.

Comment: They are predictors. I didn't want to use clustering to find what constitutes an "engaged" user. So, I took those who are loyal, and setting average of their "total reading time" and "total read articles" to define what is "engaged" i.e. users that are not in "loyal" category that have any of these predictors greater than average of loyal groups, or "not engaged" when any of the condition for greater than these two average values is not satisfied. 
I wanted some noise in the data in order to have predict_proba to return some scores like 40%, 63%, 70% and not in the majority of cases 0 or 100%

Comment: I'd drop "total read articles" and "total reading time" from your predictors, and see if the other predictors have any power.

Comment: other predictors are sparse data mostly, and have little (cor)relation with the target that I created using "total read articles" and "total reading time". The reason I left them in the model is to intencionally create noise so that I get scores that are not either 0 or 1 with sklearn's predict_proba, but something more floating point in that range. I noticed that working with RF, these 0 and 1 are returned, but Logistic regression or MLP, gives me values in that range. I might consider these last two options.